# Rewrite rule for friendly URLs to yazidetay.php is not working from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

I'm trying to get SEO Friendly URLs to work for my website using the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /yazidetay.php\?yazi_sef=([^&]+)&id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /yazidetay.php?id=$1&yazi_sef=$2 [L]
```

i want it to change

```
/yazidetay.php?yazi_sef=deneme-yazisi&id=8
```

to

```
/yazidetay.php/deneme-yazisi/8
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect non-friendly to friendly AND internally rewrite friendly to non-friendly?

Comment: One issue might be that the rewrites don't include the "yazidetay.php" part, e.g. `RewriteRule ^ /yazidetay.php/%1/%2/?` and `RewriteRule ^yazidetay.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$`. It might help to describe what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: [This testing tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) doesn't support `%{THE_REQUEST}`, but here's a test of a similar [redirect](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=38144ecb-510b-5856-8d12-ffd2f8ad146b) and [rewrite](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=68e18494-0d87-5877-b3ac-394e67c4e4c0).